# How to ignore optional parameter in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

i created method that take 4 parameters. All of them is optional parameter and when i call the method. it does'not work
here is my function:

```
 public void MyMethod(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0, int d = 0)
{
 //My code here
}
```

and i want to call the method like this (It's work in VB.NET):

```
MyMethod(,,,50);
```

It's say argument missing   can you help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be trivially answered by looking at the documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [`named parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264739(v=vs.100).aspx). With this, you can pass in any order you want without necessary to pass the opitional parameters.

```
MyMethod(d: 50)
```

You also can pass in diferent order:

```
MyMethod(d: 50, a: 10, c: 5)
```

Another sample:

```
AnotherMethod(name: "John", age: 20, isOk: true);
```

See this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264739(v=vs.100).aspx